# How to return a value from a method that needs to perform some operations inside a Runnable?

Tags: android, view, runnable, measure

To get the width of a view when the Activity/Fragment is still measuring its views, you use a `ViewTreeObserver` or  the View's post method with your own `Runnable`. I usually adopt de second one. But now -after some calculations, I would like to return the value, but because the method `run` doesn’t return any value (`void`), and I must way to measure the width of the view, I have come to a dead end. Has someone any idea?

Thanks!

```
int getDesiredWidth(final View view) {
    final int[]finalWidth = {0};

    view.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int width = view.getLayoutParams().width;
            //Calculate 'finalWidth' computing margins and other size's view
            return finalWidth[0]; //error: cannot return a value from a method with void type
        }
    });

    return finalWidth[0];
}
```

Comment: you need to use a `Callable` instead.

Comment: you can either set a class member or use  a listener/delegate

Comment: You may be looking for [Callable Futures](http://www.journaldev.com/1090/java-callable-future-example).

Comment: @Bathsheba `view.post` does not take a `Callable` as paramter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a custom `Interface` to return a value from a different thread:

```
public interface FooBar{
    public abstract void onCalculationFinished(int result);
}
```

Then create a custom Class that extends `Runnable` with an constructor you can pas an instance of your interface to:

```
public class NameItHoweverYouLike extends Runnable{
    FooBar i;
    public NameItHoweverYouLike(FooBar interface){
        this.i = interface;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int width = view.getLayoutParams().width;
        //Calculate 'finalWidth' computing margins and other size's view
        if(i != null){
            i.onCalculationFinished(width);
        }
    }
}
```

Create a new Instance of this class and run in.

Comment: I don’t like this solution because it forces to the client of the class to implement the interface and perform his task inside it. But it seems that there is no other solution.

Comment: @valbertos Unfortunatelly there is no other solution to pass data from an async thread to another thread than an interface.

Answer (score 1):

You are quite close to technically correct decision. The only one thing which has lef to do is:

```
    public void run() {
        finalWidth[0] = view.getLayoutParams().width;
    }
```

The only one problem is that this `Runnable` object will be placed inside the message queue and will not be invoked sequentially. That means, that you should think about how to wait for internal `run()` method will be invoked. This could be archived using `CountDownLatch` object for example:

```
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

view.post(.... 

  public void run() {
            finalWidth[0] = view.getLayoutParams().width;
            latch.countDown();
  }
);

countDownLatch.await();
return finalWidth[0];
```

Comment: It's the same with the suggestion @OldCurmudgeon. It prevents that the Activity/Fragment could be load.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `BlockingQueue`.

```
int getDesiredWidth(final View view) {
    final BlockingQueue<Integer> result = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1);

    view.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            result.put(view.getLayoutParams().width);
        }
    });

    return result.take();
}
```

### **Added:**

Here's an alternative - instead of returning the `width` it returns a `Future` which will give you the `width` when asked. You just need to make sure you do not request the result until you are in a state where the message queue can continue running.

```
Future<Integer> getDesiredWidth(final View view) {
    final BlockingQueue<Integer> result = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1);

    view.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            result.put(view.getLayoutParams().width);
        }
    });

    return new Future<Integer> () {

        @Override
        public boolean cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning) {
            // Cannot imterrupt it.
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCancelled() {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isDone() {
            return result.peek() != null;
        }

        @Override
        public Integer get() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
            return result.take();
        }

        @Override
        public Integer get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
            return result.poll(timeout, unit);
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: This suggestion prevents that the Activity/Fragment could be load. Log last message: threadid=1: still suspended after undo

Comment: @valbertos - It shouldn't. The `take` will block until `put` is called in the `Runnable`, that is the only blocking process.

Comment: But I've tested your suggestion and the FragmentActivity is never load. Could you try yourself please?

Comment: @valbertos - I do not have an Android environment. Research suggests that `BlockingQueue` **is** available. However, I see that `View.post` *Causes the Runnable to be added to the message queue.* so you may find this will not work as you are then waiting for the runnable to complete before exiting and probably therefore blocking the message queue. I think what you are asking is impossible.

Comment: @valbertos - Added another option.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this option doesn't work. When I try to retrieve the value from the method caller, the application is hung. Future<Integer> future = paginate_horizontal_scroll.getDesiredWidth(findViewById(R.id.iv_indicator));
            int width = future.get();

Comment: @valbertos - I thought as much. You are attempting to reach across between two threads, one of which is the message queue so `get` will only work in a very contrived environment or when the message queue has finished processing. I think you need to redesign your requirements. You could try checking `isDone` until it returns true but do not spin on that.

Comment: Me too :) Finally I've ended up with the "interface approach", like @Gumbo suggested. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating your variable `int width` within the method run, have you tried using a global variable (class member) ?

You will then be able to use the variable within the whole class.

Comment: Sorry. I should have said that the method is not called from the class itself

Comment: In that case you could create a new class that would store data. If you make that class a singleton, you will be able to call the instance and still have the value that you previously stored.

Comment: @Simpsons possible edit. A static global variable would only have one instance.